# Safari Double Margin Bug - CSS Float Layout

Tags: css, safari

I have made a css layout which has one list with 30 items in it. Each li is 9% width with 1% margin right and bottom. I alternate the float direction on each row from left to right and it looks fine in all browsers except for Safari, this is all versions of safari. It seems to have a double margin

Problem can be seen [here](http://jsfiddle.net/G5dD9/2/)

Many thanks

HTML

```
<ul class="clearfix">
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
    <li>6</li>
    <li>7</li>
    <li>8</li>
    <li>9</li>
    <li>10</li>
    <li>11</li>
    <li>12</li>
    <li>13</li>
    <li>14</li>
    <li>15</li>
    <li>16</li>
    <li>17</li>
    <li>18</li>
    <li>19</li>
    <li>20</li>
    <li>21</li>
    <li>22</li>
    <li>23</li>
    <li>24</li>
    <li>25</li>
    <li>26</li>
    <li>27</li>
    <li>28</li>
    <li>29</li>
    <li>30</li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
* {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.clearfix:before, .clearfix:after {
    content: " ";
    display: table;
}
.clearfix:after {
    clear: both;
}
ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
li {
    border: 1px solid rgba(1, 1, 1, 0.1);
    border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 0 #FFFFFF inset;
    float: left;
    height: 80px;
    list-style: none outside none;
    margin: 0 1% 1% 0;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: normal;
    width: 9%;
}
li:nth-child(n+11) {
    background: red;
    float: right;
}
li:nth-child(n+21) {
    background: blue;
    float: left;
}
li:nth-child(n+31) {
    background: red;
    float: right;
}
li:nth-child(n+41) {
    background: blue;
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: Hm, renders exactly the same for me in Chrome and Safari (Mac).

Comment: @ralph.m is twice webkit. Compare it with firefox.

Comment: Same for me in Firefox, too. :-)

Comment: @ralph.m I see a difference: the second row is indented in safari, but not in firefox

Comment: Renders the same for Chrome and Safari on mac, which are both broken.

Comment: I dont want the indent, i want to make them line up like it does in firefox, ie and chrome on pc

Comment: Why do you need to alternate between left and right? It makes no sense to me if you want them to be lined up anyway.

This might have something to do with how webkit rounds subpixels down, in which case there's not much you can do about it

Comment: I am making a snakes and ladders type of layout so they need to flow like that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this behaviour is caused by how Webkit handles **subpixels**. Subpixels are when you use a percentage of a width that doesn't end up as a whole pixel. For instance, what is 50% of 95px?

All browsers handle this problem in their own way - [John Resig](http://ejohn.org/blog/sub-pixel-problems-in-css/) has done some writing on that - but the issue here might be that webkit rounds subpixels *down*. If you resize the rendering window in Safari you'll find that the indent isn't always as wide, it almost shrinks back into place but at the next subpixel breakpoint the indent is larger again.

So how to solve it? You could target the 11th/21st/31st etc `li` and give it a larger margin. 1.2% seemed ok when I experimented with the jsfiddle. I'm afraid I can't come up with a more clean solution.

Comment: Thank you Nils. This is the best answer that I have found, and I have been searching the whole internet for a while.